# Mongodb scripting Positional operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking at updating array objects in mongodb documents as below

```
var cursor = db.coll.find();
cursor.forEach(function(x){
  if(x.arr) {
    x.arr.forEach(function(y,i){
      if(y.field1) {
        db.coll.update({_id: x._id}, {$set:{'arr.'+i+'.field1': 'x' + y.field1}})
      }
    })
  }
})
```

I get a syntax error at `{$set:{'arr.'+i+'.field1': 'x' + y.field1}}` 
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to dynamically assign values to the key of JavaScript object at the initialization time. Just create it separately and assign the key at a later step.

```
var cursor = db.coll.find();
cursor.forEach(function(x){
  if(x.arr) {
    x.arr.forEach(function(y,i){
      if(y.field1) {
        var setStmt = {};
        setStmt['arr.'+i+'.field1'] = 'x' + y.field1;
        db.coll.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: setStmt});
      }
    })
  }
})
```